# Using jQuery how to select the first next element(s) that matches a certain selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to select a node after `$(this)` that matches a certain selector?

eg:

```
<textarea id="foo"></textarea>
<a href="#">someLink</a>
<a href="#">someOtherLink</a>
<textarea id="bar"></textarea>
```

With out directly selecting #bar via $("#bar"), how can i select it from within #foo?

Comment: What's the rule/selector you're trying to match on? textarea?

Comment: @Paul Schreiber: The first next textarea.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use the [nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) method:

```
$("#foo").nextAll("textarea").first();
```

Or:

```
$("#foo").nextAll("textarea:first");
```

Or even:

```
$("#foo").nextAll("textarea:eq(0)");
```

Comment: +1. I think `.nextAll("textarea:first")` will let it stop searching just after the first textarea it finds, but, small optimization anyway.

Comment: @box9, you're right, I added other ways to do the same. Thanks :)

Comment: @David Thanks, I was in need of this because I have almost thousands of siblling elements which take years Jquery to traverse :)

Answer (score 2):

Check out [siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

```
$('#foo').siblings('textarea:first').addClass('found');
```

[jsbin demo here](http://jsbin.com/opeyo4/3/)

Comment: Cool! I just did that for effect :-)

Comment: I up-voted :) , btw do you happen to know what the difference is from nextAll?

Comment: (thanks for the upvote!) -- The way I understand it: nextAll() will get any successors to the element you specify. siblings() will get all siblings (whether they come before or after the element you specify). That's why I used textarea:first in the siblings selector, to take care of that. But nextAll would definitely be the better solution in this case. Kudos to Frédéric!